Is virtually all THC absorbed by the lungs in only a few seconds?
I was trying to find some authoritative sources on breath-hold duration and the absorption rate of vaped drugs, such as THC, but all I can find are unsourced claims like:

Virtually all of the drug is absorbed in only a few seconds, so no need to hold your breath."
"[Unspecified] research suggests that the majority of THC is absorbed within the first few seconds of inhaling...."

I can't find objective or authoritative sources that address the underlying question of whether and to what extent more drug is absorbed when vapor is held in the lungs as opposed to immediately exhaled – whether the drug is nicotine or cannabis compounds from e-cig "vape" devices.
(I've followed some claims that "10 seconds is optimal" back to this 1989 paper, but that dealt with smoking, the conclusion was unclear, and there's no reason to believe that vapor bears and transmits drugs the same way as combustion byproducts.)
(ETA: I am skeptical of these claims based on my observation that people who vape exhale visible vapor, so clearly something is going in and coming back out.  Maybe THC is not part of the visible vapor, but the simplest hypothesis is that the THC and visible vapor are associated, and the lungs don't have a mechanism for separating them that quickly.)

I went a'researching, and I found a paper that I thought was a great answer to the question, and then I realised it was by the same authors - and probably the same experiment - as the one you quoted, so I don't know whether you will accept it. Perhaps you could further explain your objections. Doesn't it explain, practically, that breath-holding doesn't increase the marijuana high?

@Oddthinking They evaluated "physiological, cognitive and subjective response to marijuana smoke."  Specifically, they measured "typical marijuana effects (increased heart rate, increased ratings of "high" and impaired memory performance)."  Burning weed ≠ vaporized distillate, and who knows how typical effects relate to THC dose (almost certainly non-linear). To address the question here researchers can measure how much THC is in a volume of vapor, how much ends up in blood samples, and/or how much is left in exhaled vapor.

Let me summarise to check I have understood: Research shows holding your breath increases some of the bad stuff (CO absorption) and doesn't affect some of the "good" stuff (the strength and nature of the high). The notable claims go slightly further, and make claims of a mechanism (i.e. rate of absorption of THC). You accept the  general advice, but are challenging the details of the mechanism - it may be plausible, but isn't conclusive.

@Oddthinking Right: Given that study it is plausible that all THC in smoke that can be absorbed via lungs is absorbed practically immediately.  I don't think the study is very good for addressing that assertion.  Furthermore, even if it did address it we would be left wondering whether what is true of combustion smoke is equally true of vaporized distillate.

Re: Visible vapour: I would suggest a slightly different interpretation of "virtually all" and "the majority". I don't think they mean "virtually all of the THC in the smoke". I think they mean "virtually of the THC that would be absorbed if you held your breath for a reasonably long time". I would imagine (without any evidence at hand to support me) that that is still only a small percentage of the total THC.

No.  According to Clinical effects and plasma levels of Δ9-Tetrahydrocannabinol (Δ9-THC) in heavy and light users of cannabis, heavy (experienced) users of cannabis achieve 23% systemic availability of THC, while light users only achieved 10% availability.
In other words, the smoking technique matters a lot and even experienced users are losing most of the THC.
